# Unity3D - Mesh.colors is extremely slow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

*Update (solved): The horrible performance was because I didn't realize that Mesh.vertices.Length does an Array copy on every call.*

I need to procedurally generate a mesh of quads.   Ideally I would like to be able to change the color of individual quads.  However it's okay if color variance only occurs on the x-axis (see photo below).

However setting Mesh.Colors is *very* *slow*.  For example, setting colors for 100,000 vertices takes ~10000 milliseconds.   How can I do this more performantly? Am I doing something wrong?

```
void CreateMesh()
{
    Mesh.Clear();
    Mesh.vertices = Vertices.ToArray();
    Mesh.triangles = Triangles.ToArray();

    // Set Colors to Mesh
    Color32[] colors = new Color32[] { new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255), new Color32(255, 0, 255, 255), new Color32(0, 0, 255, 255) };
    Color32[] colorsArray = new Color32[Mesh.vertices.Length];

    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();     
    for (int i = 0; i < Mesh.vertices.Length; i++)
        colorsArray[i] = colors[rnd.Next(0, 2)];

    Mesh.colors32 = colorsArray;
}
```

Comment: Note there's a [Mesh.MarkDynamic()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.MarkDynamic.html) function you may want to give a try. Outside of that, to get some background (which may help with the answers), why do you need to dynamically generate the meshes and mesh colors?

Comment: I tried MarkDynamic(), but it didn't seem to have a noticeable impact on performance.  

What I am trying to do is set different colors for each quad.

Comment: Random isn't that fast.

Comment: Would a variety of say 10 premade materials (maybe rotated in steps of 90 degrees on top) work for you in terms of solving color variance?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.   (note: I'm new to game dev)

Currently I have a single mesh, which generates thousands of quads. 

Having all quads have the same color is simple: I set a material for the mesh and set a color on that material.   

Is it possible to set multiple materials on a single mesh?

Comment: Also, it's okay if colors only vary on the x axis (see updated photo)

Comment: it should (should) be faster (though you have to try to really know) if you create just one matrial with an atlas texture and use UVs to color the mesh. but like @PhilippLenssen also said, it might be helpful to know what exactly you need that for.

Comment: I solved the problem, I didn't realize that Mesh.vertices.length does a array copy on every call.

Answer (score 3):

So I didn't realize that `Mesh.vertices.length` does an array copy on every call. WHAT!?

Calculating the length before fixes this problem:

```
void CreateMesh()
{
    Mesh.Clear();
    Mesh.vertices = Vertices.ToArray();
    Mesh.triangles = Triangles.ToArray();
    Mesh.MarkDynamic();

    int len = Mesh.vertices.Length;

    // Set Colors to Mesh
    Color32[] colors = new Color32[] { new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255), new Color32(255, 0, 255, 255), new Color32(0, 0, 255, 255) };
    Color32[] colorsArray = new Color32[len];

    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();     
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        colorsArray[i] = colors[rnd.Next(0, 2)];

    Mesh.colors32 = colorsArray;
}
```